# Is there a way to link to a commit on GitHub without specifying repo path?

Tags: github

I am trying to automate links to commits in GitHub Enterprise from our issue tracking system (TargetProcess). The commit hash is already referenced in TP and I'd like to make it clickable so that it takes you directly to that commit in GHE.

Is there a way to 'quick link' to the commit hash on GHE without having to specify the repo path in the URL?